# Change UIActivityViewController UINavigationBar color

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uiactivityviewcontroller

i tried changing `UIActivityViewController` by subclassing it but it never worked, also trying to set it before presenting :
   `activityViewController.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()`

Is there is any possible way to do that ? at least to change bar button item tint colors !

**Note:** I dont want to change my current navigationbar colors, just inside the `UIActivityViewController` !!

Answer (score 0):

Following code maybe help you:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]}];
```

It's code help u so try my code